# Last entered user in not caught

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 5, the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#generating-the-login-form) describe the way how to build a login form.

On the security controller, the method login ask for the last entered user through `getLastUsername` method:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername, 
            'error' => $error,

        ]);
    }
}
```

This is not working. When a logged in, then logout and go again on the login page, the `lastusername` is not caught. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Hello Mulot. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224723/getlastusername-from-authenticationutils-always-empty

Comment: Sometimes, in DEV environment and without HTTPS protocol the security doesn't work as expected... Did you try in prod and with HTTPS ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The post you've refered is not slove yet, but I didn't test in prod mode.  I will try and confirm it.